# Update javascript content on website to allow dynamical javascript insertion

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am inserting content into my website dynamically using javascript. The inserted content includes a datetime objects of the format

```
{{ moment(job.posting_date).fromNow() }}
```

using flask-moment. However, this date does not get displayed? If I refresh the site it gets displayed, just the dynamical insertion does not seem to process the moment function? How can I tell the website to update all javascript content?
thanks
carl

EDIT:
Here is how I insert the code in my page. Depending on what the user selects I use ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ url_for('job_market') }}",
    type: "POST",  
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ stuff: stuff }, null, '\t'),
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.success){
            job_table.innerHTML = data.html;
        }
        else{
            console.log("Error = ", data.error);
        }
    }
 });
```

within flask I do something like this

```
@app.route('/job_market', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def job_market(page=1):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        // get the user selection from json
        // access the necessary parts in the database (job)
        ....
        html = render_template('/job_table.html', job=job)
        // send that information back
        return json.dumps({'success': success, 'html': html}), 200,  {'ContentType':'application/json'}
```

EDIT: This is how I include moment.js

```
from flask_moment import Moment
moment = Moment()
moment.init_app(app)
```

Comment: flask is server code , it doesn't run in browser. It's job is long over by the time browser gets the page. Show your javscript insertion code

Comment: I added the information how I include the code... the moment function is part of the job_table.html template

Comment: Ok...I misunderstood issue then and see all the html rendering is on server. If the ajax is succeeding then your problem would be in `job_table.html` not javascript. Not clear if ajax works or not